# Curl returning the http response of json by escaping the forward slash

Tags: php, json, curl, laravel-5, httpie

I am trying to build REST Api in laravel and my API returns a download link of file as json response. 
However I am stuck with an issue while accessing the api via Curl.
I have used json_encode with JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES as well while creating a response but that did not work. 
The API works fine with httpie CLI but it adds escape character for forward slashes.

```
gaurav@debian:~$ curl -i  -w "\n" http://10.23.251.42:8000/api/url
"http:\/\/10.23.56.41\/abc\/xyz"
gaurav@debian:~$ http http://10.23.251.42:8000/api/url
"http://10.23.56.41/abc/xyz"
```

Can someone let me know if I have to provide some additional parameter to format the JSON output properly to unescape the forward slash ?

Comment: please use the text formatting tools to make your question more readable.

Comment: @adolfosrs Do you have any pointers to fix this.